# How to read post request without knowing variables passed?

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to read a post request sent from a client using `PHP` whether they pass variables or not. What I want is to read the post data. I have tried using, the following without any luck:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I have tried sending the post request to http://posttestserver.com/ and the `HTTP Post` returns `200` and shows the post data sent to it.

How do I go about this using php?

Comment: `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` works for me. What were you expecting to see, and what did you get instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can read the post data from the `$_POST` variable. If you want to know which keys the array holds, use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$postKeys = array_keys($_POST);
```

Alternatively, you could use `foreach` to scan the array:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: I tried sending a post request from a form and it displays the data. But, I'm sending a post request from an electronic device (a sensor) and can't see the data.

Comment: I don't know what is the device, but make sure you are actually sending a POST request and not GET. You could also try to replace `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST`. This is an an associative array that contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.